# Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Can someone help me finish the proof? I am basing off this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887077).

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $pq$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$. If there exist elements $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|=p$ and $|b|=q$, show that $G$ is cyclic.

After showing that $g^{pq}=e$, what do I do for the cases where $g=e$, $g^{p}=e$, and $g^{q}=e$? Any hints?

Comment: You need more than $p,q$ coprime.  After all we can write the order of any finite group as the product of two coprime integers.   I suspect you mean to assume $p,q$ are distinct (positive) primes, and from this the conclusion follows.

Comment: @hardmath I see! That helps a lot. For some reason, the question in the textbook does not state this assumption so it must be common knowledge.

Comment: My guess is that  $p,q $ are assumed to be primes, perhaps throughout a chapter or section of the book.  It’s easy to lose sight of when looking at an exercise or proposition in isolation.  Citing the text would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now $g=ab$.
Case 1: $g=e$. Then $a=b^{-1}$. Hence $p=|a|=|b^{-1}|=|b|=q$, a contradiction.
Case 2: $g^p=e$. That is, $$(ab)^p=e\implies a^pb^p=e\implies b^p=e$$
which means that $q$ divides $p$, a contradiction.
Case 3: $g^q=e$. Similar to case 2.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear, easy-to-understand answer!