# Group theory problem - the order of elements

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Given a group $G$, $a,b\in G$, $ab=ba$, $o(a)=n$, $o(b)=m$.

If $\gcd(n,m)\ne 1$, and $(a)\cap (b) = \{e\}$, prove that $o(ab)=\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$.

P.S. $(a)$ denotes the cyclic group generated by the element $a$.

---

I’m a little confused... Aren’t the conditions after “if” contradictory?

---

Thanks for your help down there.
But...can someone show me how to prove this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are they contradictory? How does $\gcd(n,m)\neq 1$ and $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle = \{e\}$ contradict each other?

Comment: There's no contradiction, think, for example, of the group $G=C_2\times C_3$ ($C_n$=the cyclic group of order $n$) and take $a=(x,1)$ and $b=(1,y)$, with $x\in C_2$ and $y\in C_3$ non-trivial

Comment: Suppose a is an operation to rotate something clockwise 90 degrees, b is 60 degrees. then $a^2=b^3$, meaning these two cyclic groups have more than one element in common. I just can’t figure out an example where these two conditions are not contradictory..

Comment: Well, what if $a$ and $b$ are rotating *different* things, and each of them leaves the other thing unchanged? Also, look at the xample that kneidell gave.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah that makes sense. But still I need a proof of this problem. QAQ

Comment: @kneidell thank u so much

Comment: Let $k=\operatorname{lcm}(n, m).$  Can you show $(ab)^k=1$?  If so, then all you have left to do is show that for $r \lt k, (ab)^r \neq 1$.

Comment: I can't find this *exact* question, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887233/let-g-be-an-abelian-group-of-order-pq-with-gcdp-q-1-show-that-g-is-cy?rq=1) is very similar